# How to copy the contents in google spreadsheet by using apps script. (I want to paste those contents to excel..)

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I'd like to copy the contents(lot of contents) in spreadsheet and paste them to excel.
I just tried using macro but it didn't work at all..

```
function myFunction1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2:C500');
};
```

I also tried using copyTo().. it only worked when copying the contents to the same spreadsheet.

This is my first time using apps script..
Could anyone help me solve this problem? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unfortunately Google Apps Script does not allow you to copy contents from a Google Spreadsheet to an Excel file.

What you can do instead is to export the whole Spreadsheet to Excel, or - if you do not want to copy everything:

1. Copy the data of interest from your Google Spreadsheet into an empty Google spreadsheet.
2. Export the new Google Spreadsheet to Excel.

To export a Google Spreadsheet to an Excel file you can do the following:

```js
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=" +id + "&exportFormat=xlsx", {headers: {"authorization": "Bearer" +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getBlob();

  DriveApp.createFile(blob.setName("myExcel.xlsx"));
```

Thereby is `id` the Id of your Google spreadsheet.

See more:

- [UrlfetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob())